# Issue while loading data using data.sql in springboot app during startup

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am trying to load the data in the tables which are created by JPA for entities present in the code. But I  am not able to do it. Could you please help me to understand what the thing I am doing wrong.

Important thing to note is tables are created successfully in the H2
[image: screenshot of tables]

Entity code
`

```
package org.learn.AccountOpeningDemo.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
public class Customer{

    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  As for this exercise creation of customer is not in scope so generation is not considered.
    @Column
    private long customerId;

    @Column
    private String customerName;

    @Column
    private String Surname;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CustomerAccount> customerAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

`

data.sql content
`

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney');
```

`

Application properties
`

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:C:/users/rmbid/test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
#spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

`

but getting below error
`

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59524,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\rmbid\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\Downloads\AccountOpeningDemo\target\classes;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.6.13\spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.13\spring-boot-starter-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.13\spring-boot-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.13\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.6.13\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.29\snakeyaml-1.29.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.6.13\spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.4.2\jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.4\jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.4\jackson-core-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.6.13\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.68\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.68\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.68.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.68\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.23\spring-web-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.23\spring-beans-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.23\spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.23\spring-aop-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.23\spring-context-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.23\spring-expression-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.6.13\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.6.13\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.6.13\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.6.13.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.23\spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.12.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.11.22\byte-buddy-1.11.22.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.7\jaxb-runtime-2.3.7.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.7\txw2-2.3.7.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.6.9\spring-data-jpa-2.6.9.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.6.9\spring-data-commons-2.6.9.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.23\spring-orm-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.23\spring-tx-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.23\spring-aspects-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.200\h2-1.4.200.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.24\lombok-1.18.24.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.23\spring-core-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rmbid\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.23\spring-jcl-5.3.23.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.learn.AccountOpeningDemo.AccountOpeningDemoApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59524', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.6.13)

2022-12-15 20:22:35.064  INFO 9964 --- [           main] o.l.A.AccountOpeningDemoApplication      : Starting AccountOpeningDemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_181 on DESKTOP-JP0UGO5 with PID 9964 (C:\Users\rmbid\Downloads\AccountOpeningDemo\target\classes started by rmbid in C:\Users\rmbid\Downloads\AccountOpeningDemo)
2022-12-15 20:22:35.064  INFO 9964 --- [           main] o.l.A.AccountOpeningDemoApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-15 20:22:36.906  INFO 9964 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-15 20:22:37.047  INFO 9964 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 116 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-15 20:22:39.344  INFO 9964 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-15 20:22:39.375  INFO 9964 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-15 20:22:39.375  INFO 9964 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2022-12-15 20:22:39.735  INFO 9964 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-15 20:22:39.735  INFO 9964 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4468 ms
2022-12-15 20:22:39.813  INFO 9964 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-15 20:22:40.442  INFO 9964 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-12-15 20:22:40.473  INFO 9964 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:test'
2022-12-15 20:22:40.688  WARN 9964 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/rmbid/Downloads/AccountOpeningDemo/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney') [42102-200]
2022-12-15 20:22:40.688  INFO 9964 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-12-15 20:22:40.704  INFO 9964 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-12-15 20:22:40.720  INFO 9964 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-15 20:22:40.751  INFO 9964 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-15 20:22:40.798 ERROR 9964 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/rmbid/Downloads/AccountOpeningDemo/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) [spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420) [spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) [spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.learn.AccountOpeningDemo.AccountOpeningDemoApplication.main(AccountOpeningDemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/rmbid/Downloads/AccountOpeningDemo/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:90) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyDataScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.6.13.jar:2.6.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney') [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7599) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1747) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 28 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59524', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

`

I tried to put the data.sql to load some data as applications startsup.

Answer (score 0):

As per Spring boot logs, it seems the connection to h2 is successful.

War Machine, what I recommend is to try querying a Database with the following combination:

"CUSTOMER" , " CUSTOMER " Or "CUSTOMER "

You will get a clue on how to go about it. Let me know when it works.

Comment: Thanks @Suchandra, but it did not work for me. May be I might have misunderstood. Do you want me to write query like below given query ?
INSERT INTO "CUSTOMER" VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney')

or something else. Because above given query works in H2 after direct execution but not via data.sql.

Comment: There you go War Machine. if this:  INSERT INTO "CUSTOMER" VALUES (1, 'george clooney', 'clooney')  query works from h2 web management UI. your database name is "CUSTOMER" not CUSTOMER. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry @Suchendra but it did not help. I tried putting same query in data.sql but it did not work.